# How to setup SSL on localhost

Tags: macos, apache, ssl

I'm trying to setup SSL and Apache on localhost. So far, I follow all the steps from:
http://www.webopius.com/content/355/getting-mamp-working-with-ssl-on-os-x

However, when I test my browsers:
From Safari It says: It can't verify the identify of website localhost.
From Chrome displays: "Site security certificate is not trusted!"

Does know how to fix that? I appreciate if anyone can point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you purchase an SSL certificate from a Certificate Authority (CA)? If not, then you've most likely got a self-signed certificate. Since no CA has 'signed' your cert, it cannot be verified as authentic, and browsers will rightfully complain about that.

If the CA's "stamp of approval" wasn't required to make a cert "valid" for a browser, it'd be beyond trivial for anyone to forge a `microsoft.com` or `google.com` certificate and pose as any site they wanted to. "Look ma, it must be google! the browser's showing the key icon!"

Comment: Nope, I didn't purchase SSL certificate from CA. Is there a way to make it run for a testing purpose in localhost?

Comment: On firefox, at least, you can allow a bad cert temporarily (or permanently). Must be something equivalent in safari somewhere - probably on the very page showing you the verification error.